# SAS EG Using DM to change color of log's messages

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm using SAS EG 5.1 for some automation and want to change colors of messages in log without using `ERROR-(red)|WARNING-(teal)|NOTE-(green)`, because of I want to get another color, blue for example. My question is how can i do this? or maybe i can change colors using  dm command like this:

```
dm log 'color note blue';

   data _null_; 
     set b;
     *****;
     putlog "NOTE-  This text must be blue in log!!!";
   run;

dm log 'color note green';
```

*Color of notes in log is green now;

Please give me correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In EG, you would need to do this via the `Tools -> SAS Programs -> Editor Options -> Appearance -> File Tyle=SAS Log File` dialog.  SAS program statements cannot generally affect EG operation; there is no `dm` equivalent in EG.  This isn't something that automation really should affect, anyway; it's not a setting in the log file itself (which is a text file) but it's actually in EG itself (how it displays a log file generated by any process).

You could have different EG setups with different settings files, if you want to use different colors for one process and not for another.

You also could probably automate the change (perhaps looking at the project name) by writing a custom EG addin using .NET.  I don't know exactly how this would be done; [Chris Hemedinger](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/) is the expert in that field and has some tips for EG automation in his blog, and also is active on [communities.sas.com](http://communities.sas.com/) in the EG community.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe are there ability to suppress the litle red x on the top Program icon that appears when i use putlog "ERROR-..." ??

Comment: You have the option in Tools->Options->Results->Results General "Change task icon when warnings occur".  I'm not so sure about errors, though, that may be unavoidable.  That's sort of on purpose, any time you specifically throw an error shouldn't that be an indication you need to look at something?

Comment: I just want to highlight one of if conditions, this is not quite an error, anyway thanks for answers

Comment: Then you should putlog "warning" or something else.  Warning will still trigger a yellow (!) if you have it set that way.